# When pressing enter in a responsive layout Bootstrap column in ckeditor it adds another column instead of a carriage return

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I am using the bootstrap plugin with an inline ckeditor. When I try to add in a responsive layout (in this case columns) I get code that looks like this.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">column 1</div>
<div class="col-md-6">column 2</div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Whenever I click in one of these columns via ckeditor and type everything works fine, when the text reaches the end of the column it continues on the next line and is formatted as expected.

example http://jsfiddle.net/gwbsp5dc/1/, this looks exactly as it should.

However if I am typing and press the enter or return key, instead of adding a new line or < br> tag like this http://jsfiddle.net/gwbsp5dc/2/ it adds a whole new column like this http://jsfiddle.net/gwbsp5dc/3/

This problem is only happening when specifically using responsive layouts and columns, when I press enter on a regular ckeditor instance it adds a

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

to the source. If I were to add the above or a < br> tag in the source the formatting works perfectly.

Comment: I am not very familiar with ckeditor, but use other WYSIWYG editors. What happens if you hit shift + enter ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the enter mode for ckeditor, it was picking up the parent container and copying it.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-enterMode

Comment: What did you change it to? BR or P? I was going to suggest wrapping the DIV contents in a <p> element but I guess this works too :)